# Installing Dell LITEON 512GB m.2 w/adapter in 13" 2015 MacBook Pro w/High Sierra, not showing up?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, disk-utility, ssd, 3rd-party

Bought one of those nifty m.2 adapters on eBay for my 2015 MacBook Pro a1502 so I could save some money on buying an OEM drive by using a cheaper 512GB LITEON nvme SSD. MacBook's firmware is up-to-date, and SSD is detected using ARCH Linux, but refuses to show up in either High Sierra Disk Utility or Sierra/El Cap Disk Utility, all from recovery mode.

What do you think? Not sure why it wouldn't be showing up given it's recognized in Linux. Tried fresh when first arrived, w/partitioning the drive w/in Arch Linux both generically and with Apple HFS/HFS+, still nothing. Have also tried with a 2015 MacBook Air, nada--recognized in Arch, nothing on El Cap/Sierra/High Sierra installers.

Comment: Maybe something in the drive firmware requires a specific driver macOS doesn't have? Just guessing here but that seems reasonable.

Comment: Didn't High Sierra's firmware update add native support for all NVMe drives? Wouldn't be sure why macOS would include driver firmware for other third party SSDs and leave out LITEON.